# Magento 2 csv import : do I need to specify a price for the configurable products?

Tags: magento2

I'm importing product into Magento 2 with a csv. Do I need to specify a price for the configurable products or can I left the price field blank? My variations are only sizes and the price is the same for each.

I'm currently not specifying it and the import works fine, but I don't want to run into issues later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to specify price for the configurable product on import.